# Read Ahead / Look Behind vs. Capture Groups

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to teach myself regex and I have a question concerning two different methods for capturing the HTTP status code (301) in the below fake apache access log. I realize that this regex would only capture the status code in this one single message, but it's just a proof of concept.

```
11.22.33.44 - - [17/Aug/2019:11:24:01 -0400] "GET /posts/posts/explore HTTP/1.0" 301 5024 "http://www.someurl.blah/faq.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/5310 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.801.0 Safari/5310"
```

So I could do this using read ahead and look behind to make a full match:

```
(?<=HTTP\/1.0"\s)(301)(?=\s5024)
```

Or I could just capture the status code in a group:

```
HTTP\/1.0"\s(?<status_code>301)
```

I'm a total noob here, but it just seems like it would be easier to capture "in between" type strings as groups as in the second example. I'm just having a disconnect understanding why I wouldn't always just capture by group. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: So your question is... "Why wouldn't I always capture by group?"  Can your question be articulated in such a way that there is an actual answer rather than just preference?  Obviously there are many ways to define what captures and what does not. You can use non-capturing groups, capturing groups, explicit and implicit capture, etc.  So what's the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is just fine, and you can get `301` without the capturing groups:

```
(?i)(?<=http\/1\.0"\s)301(?=\s[0-9]{4})
```

or with capturing groups. Sometimes, you'd want the full match to return exactly what you want without a second call to other capturing groups, and sometimes it doesn't really matter.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EZBYcL/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/EZBYcL/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

According to regex101

- The first regex [`(?<=HTTP\/1.0"\s)(301)(?=\s5024)`](https://regex101.com/r/mHPgai/1) finds 301 in 31 steps.
- The second [`HTTP\/1.0"\s(?<status_code>301)`](https://regex101.com/r/mHPgai/2) in 19 steps.